# How to execute stored procedure on ODBC Snowflake Destinastion?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'am building new package for move data from aws sql server instance to snowflake odbc destination. If i found rows which was updated i must change them on snowflake as well. In common's i found only 'OLE DB Command' for execute procedure for update diffrent rows.

The problem is i need something like "ODBC Command" for execute procedure to update diffrent rows between SQL Server&Snowflake.

Comment: The way this is usually achieved is you load all the changed rows into a staging table in the target (snowflake) then you run a single INSERT and a single UPDATE to merge the records into the target from the staging table. The execute SQL command should work on whatever connection manager you have (which I assume is Snowflake ODBC)

Comment: I like what @Nick.McDermaid said with an exception that Snowflake's *MERGE* command is preferred https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/merge.html

Comment: @Arthur is there any actual benefit to merge over seperate insert/select in snowflake?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid not really other than it is one atomic operation. Also has additional features and readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I do it.

So if u need UPDATE rows on ODBC destination in SSIS u have only one way to do that u need to use Script Component. Before I thought it will be something like ODBC Command and we will need to write stored procedure to change rows in the destination. I link that for ppl who care in the future.

> The OLE DB Command transformation runs an SQL statement for each row in a data flow. For example, you can run an SQL statement that inserts, updates, or deletes rows in a database table. 
>   [Microsoft OLE DB Command description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/ole-db-command-transformation?view=sql-server-2017)

I wrote a simple code in c# to Update Rows and it works perfectly. U can simple rebuild it for execute procedure or do whatever u need.

```
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
 {
  OdbcConnection odbcConn;
  OdbcCommand odbcCmd;
  OdbcParameter odbcParam;

public override void AcquireConnections(object Transaction)
  {
    /// Create a String base on that which u define on package for connection and 
        adding a password

    string connectionString;
    connectionString = this.Connections.SFConnection.ConnectionString;
    odbcConn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString + "PWD=YOURPASSWORD");
    odbcConn.Open();
    }

public override void PreExecute()
{
    ///Create command which we wanna execute

    base.PreExecute();
    odbcCmd = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE klienci SET IMIE= ?,NAZWISKO= ? ,NUMER_TELEFONU= ? ,EMAIL= ? ,ULICA= ? ,MIASTO= ? ,STATE= ? ,ZIP_CODE = ? WHERE CUSTOMER_ID= ?", odbcConn);

}

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
      ///Adding parameters and connecting them with our input column from package

    odbcCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IMIE", Row.Sourcefirstname);
    odbcCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAZWISKO", Row.Sourcelastname);
    odbcCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NUMER_TELEFONU", Row.Sourcephone);
    odbcCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMAIL", Row.Sourceemail);
    odbcCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ULICA", Row.Sourcestreet);
    odbcCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MIASTO", Row.Sourcecity);
    odbcCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATE", Row.Sourcestate);
    odbcCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZIP_CODE", Row.Sourcezipcode);
    odbcCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CUSTOMER_ID", Row.Sourcecustomerid);
    odbcCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
}
```